# Density Map With Agent

Tags: anylogic

I'm tring to obtain a density map with agents.
I've made the agentification of the network, so each elements is an agent and I want to change the color of the density map in the square where a person pass.
What I've made is to drag a canvas and change the color of the whole canvas as the models start. Then in my moving agent (on step actions) i wrote the following code:

double x = getX();

double y = getY();

Color cc;

cc=model.rectangle1.getFillColor(); // blu rectangle

model.canvas.fillRectangle(x* 5, y* 5, 5, 5, cc );

But nothing change,
Have you got any suggestion on how to work with canvas? [image]

Comment: if you did the network agentification from my videos (?), I am not sure if the canvas would even work. Now that you have everything as agents, you can easily change colors based on anything. Count how many arrive/exit and set your colors accordingly, no?

Comment: Yes, I've seen your videos. I know that is possible to change color by counting enter/ exit, as a first step i've changed the color of the path based on how many people have passed. But, Density Map tool has a better visual effect, easier to understand. I saw an example with the use of canvas (wandering elephant) and it's quite complex, but I was wondering how it could be introduced by working with the agentification of the model.